# rendering pdf documents - fonts - HiDPI (High Dots Per Inch) display

Tags: display, pdf, fonts, resolution

I recently bought a new Dell laptop with a high-resolution screen (3200x1800). For my work I have to read and write perhaps 10 hours a day. Coming from a 17 inch 1920x1080 experience, something feels not right... I feel "over stimulated" in a negative way, making it difficult for my eyes to focus. I cannot describe the negative effect very well. It just feels "this is too much to handle." I put brightness lower. I even changed resolution to 1920x1080. But not much improvement. I suppose there is something wrong with rendering PDF documents on a [HiDPI](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/HiDPI_display_support) (High Dots Per Inch) display.

To put the question in a more objective way.

- What could cause this strain on my eyes? Is it really the high dots per inch that physically affect my eyes? If so, if I lower the resolution in windows why is the problem not solved?
- Is it possible that my screen (or graphic card) doesn't render fonts in PDF properly? If so, what would be a good way to make the fonts on my computer more compatible with my hardware.

On a side note: the fonts in my browser (e.g. firefox) seem to be well-scaled and good. Also the Windows 8 interface fonts are sharp and clear. The problem seems to be local, specific for PDF files.

Comment: Try different PDF reader(s).

Comment: Forgot to mention that, I tried 5 different ones (foxit, x-change pdf editor, summatrapdf, etc.)